# Why did a bunch of people (including me) get a marshal badge all at once?

Tags: support, badges

https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/132/marshal

A bunch of people got the marshal badge all at once (including me, even though I have it, it awarded me a second one). Why did this happen? I have over 1000 helpful flags but I've had that for awhile, so why *right now*?

Edit: I was just awarded a *third* marshal badge.

Comment: According to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#188732), the Marshal badge is only supposed to be awarded once. The same thing happened to me on MathOverflow, so it seems that this is a network-wide issue.

Comment: I have over 3000 flags, so I'm not sure about the new computation.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280023/excavator-and-marshall-badges-are-being-awarded-over-and-over

Comment: I have 547 helpful flags and have now 3 marshal badges too :)

Comment: Everyone knows marshals only operate in triumvirates.

Comment: I don't have an account on the stackexchange meta, so I can't write it there, but I've noticed that the Excavator badge has not been affected here.

Comment: This is what happened: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280028/140505

Comment: @Oded: Does that mean that we're going to lose the extra badges, or that just some  people are going to lose the extra badges, and others might get more of it? (Like the Socratic badge)

Comment: @Asaf - yeah, the extra badges will go (only 1 marshal badge to those who earned it).

Comment: @Oded:חבל... :(

Comment: @Asaf - ככה זה בחיים

Comment: @Oded: Apparently so. I always felt that if the Socratic badge can be rewarded multiple times, then the Marshal badge can be too. I guess it's just me, though.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Well but then, probably the fanatic badge as well as the electorate badge should be rewarded multiple times (in which case you'd probably end up with a lot of additional golden badges).

Comment: @Surb: I didn't consider that. But I wouldn't object either... :P

Comment: and all the review queues seem to be empty